# Variable max for form input number

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 `<inputs type="number">`. Lets call them a, b, and c. By default, a, b, and c are all 12.

I have an output, lets call it d, that displays the total of a+b+c. d should never be more than 36. How do I set the "max" value for a, b, and c to make the sum equal 36.

Some examples:

```
a=12, b=12, c=12, d=36
```

This is how it starts. To make an equal to 13, the user would have to reduce b or c by 1, then add 1 to a.

```
a=24, b=00, c=12, d=36
```

This scenario show the user reduced b by 12, and then raised a by 12.

```
a=00, b=36, c=00, d=36
```

This one show they used reduced a and c by 12, then raised b by 24.

```
a=12, b=12, c=00, d=24
```

The user reduced b by 12. The user has the potential to add 12 to a, b, or c divided as they so chose.

I can use html and/or javascript to achieve this goal.

Comment: This feels like homework.

Comment: Yeah, what real-world problem could this be solving?

Comment: You can't set a max-value for a, b or c (If you want any way it should be 36 as you can put a=36, b=0 and c=0)

Comment: A real-world example could be allocation of funds (a la Humble Bundle), where you have something like $10 to split among 3 things. That said, yeah, this very much feels like homework.

Comment: max value of a b c will be 36

Comment: This *has* to be done with JavaScript.  Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should set the max for a, b and c to 36.

Then you need to use the `onchange` event to make sure that one affects the other while you change them.

For example:

if a = 20, b=10, c=6, then d=36

if you increase c, to make it 7, then a should become 19.5 and b should become 9.5

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" id="a" max="36" value="12" onchange="Stabilized(this)" class="numbers">
<input type="number" id="b" max="36" value="12" onchange="Stabilized(this)" class="numbers">
<input type="number" id="c" max="36" value="12" onchange="Stabilized(this)" class="numbers">
<input type="number" id="d" max="36" value="36">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function Stabilized(e)
{
    var thisNumber = e.value;
    var totalSum=0;
    var i;
    var remainingSum = 36 - parseFloat(thisNumber);
    var numbersList = document.getElementsByClassName("numbers");
    var currentRemainingSum=0;
    var average;
    var y=0;
    var flag1=0;
    var counter=0;
    for (i=0;i<numbersList.length;i++)
    {
        totalSum +=parseFloat(numbersList[i].value);
        if(numbersList[i]!=e)
        {
            y++
            currentRemainingSum = parseFloat(currentRemainingSum) + (parseFloat(numbersList[i].value));
        }
    }
    if((parseFloat(currentRemainingSum))>(parseFloat(remainingSum)))
        {
            average = ((currentRemainingSum-remainingSum)/y);
            while(parseFloat(currentRemainingSum)>parseFloat(remainingSum)){
            for (i=0;i<numbersList.length;i++)
            {
                if(numbersList[i]!=e)
                {
                        if((parseFloat(numbersList[i].value))>=average){
                        numbersList[i].value = (parseFloat(numbersList[i].value) - parseFloat(average));
                        remainingSum=parseFloat(remainingSum)+parseFloat(average);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            remainingSum=(parseFloat(remainingSum)+(parseFloat(numbersList[i].value)));
                            numbersList[i].value = 0;   
                        }

                }

                if((parseFloat(currentRemainingSum)<=parseFloat(remainingSum))){
                    break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    else if((parseFloat(currentRemainingSum))<(parseFloat(remainingSum)))
    {
        average = ((remainingSum-currentRemainingSum)/y)

        for (i=0;i<numbersList.length;i++)
        {

            if(numbersList[i]!=e)
            {
                counter++;
                if(numbersList[i].value==36)
                {
                     flag1++;
                }
                else
                {
                    numbersList[i].value = (parseFloat(numbersList[i].value) + average);
                    remainingSum = remainingSum - average;
                    flag1--;
                }

            }
            if((parseFloat(remainingSum))<=0 || (flag1==counter && numbersList.length==(i+1))){
                break;}
        }

    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VxqVV/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  I am giving you logic.arrange it according to yourself.

    function sol(){
    var a=0,b=0,c=0,n=36;
    a=Math.floor(Math.random()*n);
    if(a==n){
   b=0;
   c=0;
   exit;
   }
   b=Math.floor(Math.random()*n);

  if((a+b)>n){
    sol();
    }
  else if((a+b)==n)
    {
    c=0;
    }
  else
    c=n-(a+b);
    };
```